# cached schwartzian transform

Tags: perl, caching, optimization, sorting, memoization

I'm going through "Intermediate Perl" and it's pretty cool. I just finished the section on "The Schwartzian Transform" and after it sunk in I started to wonder why the transform doesn't use a cache. In lists that have several repeated values the transform recomputes the value for each one so I thought why not use a hash to cache results. Here' some code:

```
# a place to keep our results
my %cache;

# the transformation we are interested in
sub foo {
  # expensive operations
}

# some data
my @unsorted_list = ....;

# sorting with the help of the cache
my @sorted_list = sort {
  ($cache{$a} //= &foo($a)) <=> ($cache{$b} //= &foo($b))
} @unsorted_list;
```

Am I missing something? Why isn't the cached version of the Schwartzian transform listed in books and in general just better circulated because on first glance I think the cached version should be more efficient?

**Edit**: daxim has pointed out in the comments this is known as the [orcish maneuver](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=130021). So I wasn't going crazy although I don't quite understand the name.

Comment: [Orcish maneuver](http://google.com/search?q=orcish+maneuver)?

Comment: @daxim: Haha, that's exactly it. I just didn't know the name.

Comment: Orcish is a corruption of Or Cache.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(lots of other comments redacted)

To the extent that an array lookup is more efficient than a hash lookup (i.e., `$a->[1]` is faster than `$cache{$a}`), the canonical form could be more efficient than your code, even with a lot of duplicates.

---

### Benchmark results:

Here's my benchmarking code:

```
# when does an additional layer of caching improve the performance of 
# the Schwartzian transform?

# methods:
#   1. canonical Schwartzian transform
#   2. cached transform
#   3. canonical with memoized function

# inputs:
#   1. few duplicates (rand)
#   2. many duplicates (int(rand))

# functions:
#   1. fast
#   2. slow

use Benchmark;
use Math::BigInt;
use strict qw(vars subs);
use warnings;
no warnings 'uninitialized';

# fast_foo: a cheap operation,  slow_foo: an expensive operation
sub fast_foo { my $x = shift; exp($x) }
sub slow_foo { my $x = shift; my $y = new Math::BigInt(int(exp($x))); $y->bfac() }

# XXX_memo_foo: put caching optimization inside call to 'foo'
my %fast_memo = ();
sub fast_memo_foo {
  my $x = shift;
  if (exists($fast_memo{$x})) {
    return $fast_memo{$x};
  } else {
    return $fast_memo{$x} = fast_foo($x);
  }
}

my %slow_memo = ();
sub slow_memo_foo {
  my $x = shift;
  if (exists($slow_memo{$x})) {
    return $slow_memo{$x};
  } else {
    return $slow_memo{$x} = slow_foo($x);
  }
}

my @functions = qw(fast_foo slow_foo fast_memo_foo slow_memo_foo);
my @input1 = map { 5 * rand } 1 .. 1000;         # 1000 random floats with few duplicates
my @input2 = map { int } @input1;                # 1000 random ints with many duplicates

sub canonical_ST {
  my $func = shift @_;
  my @sorted = map { $_->[0] }
    sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }
    map { [$_, $func->($_)] } @_;
  return;
}

sub cached_ST {
  my $func = shift @_;
  my %cache = ();
  my @sorted = sort {
    ($cache{$a} //= $func->($a)) <=> ($cache{$b} //= $func->{$b})
  } @_;
  return;
}

foreach my $input ('few duplicates','many duplicates') {
  my @input = $input eq 'few duplicates' ? @input1 : @input2;
  foreach my $func (@functions) {

    print "\nInput: $input\nFunction: $func\n-----------------\n";
    Benchmark::cmpthese($func =~ /slow/ ? 30 : 1000,
             {
              'Canonical' => sub { canonical_ST($func, @input) },
              'Cached'    => sub { cached_ST($func, @input) }
             });
  }
}
```

and the results (Strawberry Perl 5.12):

```
Input: few duplicates
Function: fast_foo
-----------------
           Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 160/s        --      -18%
Cached    196/s       22%        --

Input: few duplicates
Function: slow_foo
-----------------
            Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 7.41/s        --       -0%
Cached    7.41/s        0%        --

Input: few duplicates
Function: fast_memo_foo
-----------------
           Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 153/s        --      -25%
Cached    204/s       33%        --

Input: few duplicates
Function: slow_memo_foo
-----------------
            Rate    Cached Canonical
Cached    20.2/s        --       -7%
Canonical 21.8/s        8%        --

Input: many duplicates
Function: fast_foo
-----------------
           Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 179/s        --      -50%
Cached    359/s      101%        --

Input: many duplicates
Function: slow_foo
-----------------
            Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 11.8/s        --      -62%
Cached    31.0/s      161%        --

Input: many duplicates
Function: fast_memo_foo
-----------------
           Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 179/s        --      -50%
Cached    360/s      101%        --

Input: many duplicates
Function: slow_memo_foo
-----------------
            Rate Canonical    Cached
Canonical 28.2/s        --       -9%
Cached    31.0/s       10%        --
```

I'm a little stunned by these results -- the canonical Schwartzian transform has only a slight advantage under the most favorable conditions (expensive function call, few duplicates or no memoization) and is at a pretty substantial disadvantage in the other cases. The OP's caching scheme inside the `sort` function even outperforms memoization outside `sort`. I wasn't expecting this when I did the benchmarks, but I think the OP is onto something.

Comment: This still calls `foo()` on every item in `@unsorted`.  davidk01's idea was that, since there may be duplicate items in `@unsorted`, the processed values should be cached to avoid calling `foo()` again for duplicate values.

Comment: Consider the list `(2,2)` and the function `x -> x*x` then the schwartzian transform should turn that into `([2,4],[2,4])` but it is not obvious why `foo(2)` is computed only once. In this case it should be computed twice instead of once by using a cache.

Comment: I wasn't going for readability and I hadn't considered the 0 case but for lists with lots of redundancy the cached version should be faster I think because it does everything in one pass and uses lookup operations instead of subroutine calls on each element.

Comment: In that case you could just use a memoized `foo` function -- the efficiency gains could come from either inside or outside the Schwartzian transform.

Comment: Thanks for doing the benchmarks. I had only performed some trivial benchmarks myself when I posted the question. Your results are much more thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Caching the Schwartzian Transform would be useful when you're calling `foo()` in multiple transforms:

```
@sorted1 = map { $_->[0] }
           sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
           map  { [$_, foo($_)] }
           @unsorted1;
@sorted2 = map { $_->[0] }
           sort { $a->[1] cmp $b->[1] }
           map  { [$_, foo($_)] }
           @unsorted2;
```

If `@unsorted1` and `@unsorted2` have largely the same values, then you'll be calling `foo()` for the same values twice. If this function is computationally expensive, you probably want to cache the results.

The easiest way to do this would be to use the [`Memoize` module](http://perldoc.perl.org/Memoize.html):

```
use Memoize;
memoize('foo');
```

If you add these two lines, you don't have to worry about setting up a cache for `foo()` yourself, `Memoize` handles it for you.

**Edit:** I only just noticed that your sort doesn't do the Schwartzian Transform. The whole point behind the ST is that you only run your expensive function once for each member of the list, which is why you do the whole `map sort map` construct. While you probably could do some hand-written caching like how you've done, it would be non-standard Perl (in the sense that someone would be expecting to see the ST and then have to sit there and figure out what your code is doing) and could quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

But yes, if your list has repeated values, using a cache (either hand-rolled or with `Memoize`) could result in a quicker Schwartzian Transform. I say "could" because there could be instances where doing a hash lookup is actually more expensive than calling out to `foo()` (the `Memoize` docs use `sub foo { my $x = shift; return $x * $x }` as an example of one of these instances).

Comment: Thanks for the module pointer. I'm still new to the whole CPAN business and I'm just trying to understand stuff from first principles before I start using CPAN modules.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that learning CPAN /is/ a first principle when it comes to learning Perl. :-) Also, `Memoize` is a core module, so you don't have to go to CPAN to get it, you already have it.

Comment: My code does perform the schwartzian transform but instead of having `[$x, &foo($x)]` we emulate the result with `{$x => &foo($x)}` so instead of projecting onto the second component we do a hash lookup.

Comment: Actually that's not a Schwartzian Transform, it's a sort with caching. The ST forces the calculation of `foo()` for every member of the list, whereas your cached sort only calculates `foo()` for unique members of the list. The ST actually refers to the `map/sort/map` idiom and not the algorithm.

Comment: Wrong emphasis on my part then.

Comment: This answer is correct - I have concrete, benchmarked real-life program cases which use an OM inside an ST when `foo()` is computationally expensive and repetitive and it gives a significant performance boost.